# C - Changes made to text file are not noticed when the program reads the file

Tags: c, file, buffer

I am making a local chat program where the program writes to the file, and then reads the file to see if others are editing the file. I have appending to the file down just fine. However, when the file is read, it only sees the file how it was when it was first opened.
I am using `buffer = fopen("buffer.txt", "r+");` to open the file.

My reading algorithm looks like this:

```
void bufread(){
    //READING BUFFER
    fseek(buffer, -1-strlen(nick), SEEK_END);
    fgets(readbuf, 0x5FF, buffer);
    removeChar(readbuf, '\n');
    if (strcmp(readbuf, nick) == 0 )
        ;
    else{
        i = 0;
        strcpy(prevbuf, globalline);
        while(c != '\n'){
            fseek(buffer, -2, SEEK_CUR);
            c = getc(buffer);
            i++;
        }
        fgets(globalline, i, buffer);
        printf("%s\n", globalline);
    }
}
```

How do I refresh the file so that it reads the newest version of the file everytime the function is called?

EDIT: I figured it out.
The while loop only runs when c is not a newline, but it also stops when c is a newline. I did not reset c, so it stays a newline and thus the while loop doesn't execute.

Comment: We need a [mcve] to be able to help - too many unknowns at this time.

Comment: You need to show how you open the file.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, some one is changing a file while it is 'open' for reading.  To have the executing program see the latest file contents, close the file and then open it again.

Answer (score 0):

fgets, and the like buffer input.  So they may find end of file, and not be able to read past it.  You can for example re-open the file, and 'fseek' to position you got to last time.  Or maybe use a different mechanism such as pipes or sockets.

Comment: I tried reopening the file. It did not change the situation at all.

Comment: If you reopened the file, and didn't see any changes, that means there were no changes written.  Are you sure you wrote the new values from the other process? Remember about buffering, you need to either call fclose() or fflush() from the other process, to flush out whatever you wrote to disk.